# xslt to convert xml file to csv with delimiter cntl+A

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT and really hoping someone can help me out. I get an XML document from program and I need to be able to convert this to a CSV file with "cntl+A" delimiter. I am able to convert to | delimiter file.

requirement is to convert to cntl+a delimiter hence xslt should convert Unicode-\u0001  value of to cntl+A to delimiter.

xml input file

```
<Content xmlns="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07">
  <ExportXML>
    <record>
      <field name="Number">12663342</field>
      <field name="FileName">Document.pdf</field>
      <field name="LastModificationDate">2022-07-17 16:31:29</field>
    </record>
    <record>
      <field name="Number">12663324</field>
      <field name="FileName">Rishabh's| Resume.pdf</field>
      <field name="LastModificationDate">2022-07-17 06:38:44</field>
    </record>
  </ExportXML>
</Content>
```

xslt file

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:itk="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/toolkit/2005/07" xmlns:fct="http://www.taleo.com/xsl_functions" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:param name="csvDelimiter">"</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="csvQuoteCharacter">"</xsl:param>
    <!-- ======================================= -->
    <!-- Root template. -->
    <!-- ======================================= -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
        <!-- Process records. -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//itk:record"/>
        <!-- Build trailer record. -->
        <xsl:text>TRL</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(count(//itk:record), '000000000')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
 <xsl:function name="fct:nvl">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:param name="replace-with"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length($value) &gt; 0">
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$replace-with"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
    
    <!-- ======================================= -->
    <!-- Template matching each record. -->
    <!-- ======================================= -->
    <xsl:template match="itk:record">
        <xsl:for-each select="itk:field">
            <xsl:value-of select="fct:quote(.)"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="$csvDelimiter"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        
       
    </xsl:template>
    
        <!-- ======================================= -->
    <!-- Quote a value if it contains the csvDelimiter or the csvQuoteCharacter. -->
    <!-- ======================================= -->
    <xsl:function name="fct:quote">
        <xsl:param name="value"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($value, $csvDelimiter) or contains($value, $csvQuoteCharacter)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$csvQuoteCharacter"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="replace($value, $csvQuoteCharacter, concat($csvQuoteCharacter, $csvQuoteCharacter))"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$csvQuoteCharacter"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Present output file

```
12663342|Document.pdf|2022-07-17 16:31:29
12663324|"Rishabh's| Resume.pdf"|2022-07-17 06:38:44
TRL|2
```

I have never created csv file with cntl+A delimiter .I just randomly search over internet for sample file here I found the detail

below contains ^A (Unicode-\u0001) as delimiter and every line is terminated by ^B for next line File :

```
10000^AA17^Aa17^A2423^B 
10001^AA18^Aa18^A2423^B 
10002^AA19^Aa19^A2423^B 
10003^AA20^Aa20^A2423^B
```

Comment: What exactly is *"cntl+A" delimiter*?

Comment: You see the `csvDelimiter` used for separating fields, and actually resulting in `|`. The reason is that it is a parameter of the stylesheet passed from the code. Either alter the code, or replace the uses of `$csvDelimiter` either with `\u0001` (inside string) and `'\u0001'` (as string). Or better `&#1;`.

Comment: @JoopEggen `&#1;` is not a valid XML character.

Comment: @michael.hor257k so true! Though I did read someone using `&#x1;`. Maybe within a CDATA? Or something with a function à la "chr(1)".

Comment: cntl+A is a delimiter just like comma or pipe symbol(|) .. the ascii form for ctrl A is '/u0001'

Comment: I have never created with  cntl+A delimiter .I just randomly search over internet for sample file here I found the detail  ```  contains ^A as delimeter and every line is terminated by ^B for next line

 

File :

10000^AA17^Aa17^A2423^B
10001^AA18^Aa18^A2423^B
10002^AA19^Aa19^A2423^B
10003^AA20^Aa20^A2423^B ````

Comment: `&#1;` is a valid character in XML 1.1, just not in XML 1.0. So long as the stylesheet is declared as an XML 1.1 document then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set your `csvDelimiter` parameter to the Control-A value, e.g. like so:

```xml
<xsl:param name="csvDelimiter">&#1;</xsl:param>
```

But you will also need to add an XML declaration to the start of your stylesheet file, like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.1"?>
```

The reason is that the Control-A character, `&#1;`, is not a valid character in XML version 1.0. In the most recent version of XML, namely version 1.1, this character (along with several other control characters) *is* allowed, but if your XSLT file lacks an XML declaration then it is, by default, an XML 1.0 file, i.e. an XML file with no XML declaration is effectively treated as if it had the declaration `<?xml version="1.0">`.

Comment: And be aware that many XML tools, for example those from Microsoft, do not support XML version 1.1.

Comment: I think since the stylesheet is XSLT 2.0 I'd be hopeful that XML 1.1 would be supported

Comment: Several vendors, including Saxonica, have produced XSLT 2.0+ processors on .NET that rely on Microsoft's XML parser technology, which has never supported XML 1.1.

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know. I've generally avoided working with the .NET platform all these years so I've never had to face that, though to be honest I've only rarely needed XML 1.1's expanded character set either.

Answer (score 0):

The essential problem here is that XSLT only handles the XML character set, even when generating CSV files which are not XML, and \u0001 is not available in the XML 1.0 character set - though it is available in XML 1.1.

If you can't use XML 1.1, one workaround would be to use a different character, and then post-process the output using a tool such as sed. You could even do this post-processing "inline" in a custom Stream supplied as the output destination of your XSLT processor (the details depend on your chosen XSLT processor and its API).